# Getting different result using "run" button and "run this cell" button for the same body of code in python

Tags: python, spyder

I use "run" button to run the whole body of my code. I also choose the whole body of code and push the "run this cell" button and get different results. I am using "spyder" to write my code. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, which one?

Comment: Ys I am using Spyder

Comment: please add this to your question otherwise it is too ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe you have variables in memory, check it in spyder variable explorer, or paste here your exact code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No its not. How can I attach the code to this post? My code is huge (more than 300 lines) so I can not add it to my question

Answer (score 7):

@Fairy, a "cell" in spyder is defined by using a special comment

`# %% Cell defined here`

Are you using this?

**Update**

@Fairy, you need to use the cell syntax so:

```
# %% Cell 1
a = 1       # Start of Cell 1
b = 2
print(a*b)  # End of Cell 1

# %% Cell 2
c = 1.0     # Start of Cell 2
d = 2
print(a/b)  # End of Cell 1
```

Now you can run cells, that are delimited by the special comment

Comment: No really. I just select the whole code by "ctrl+A" and then push the "run this cell button"